# Onblur,Onfocus javascript for TextMode="MultiLine" not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I've got a multiline asp.textbox input control.

I don't know if my issue is with ASP.NET, the Multiline control, or something else, but the onblur and onfocus are not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var defaultMsg = 'Write your message here or or call my voice at (xxx) xxx-xxxx.';
  var controlMsg = doc.createElement("input");
  controlMsg.id = "txtMessage";
  controlMsg.type = "text";
  controlMsg.value = defaultMsg;
  controlMsg.onfocus=function jpFocus() { if (this.value == defaultMsg) this.value = ''; }
  controlMsg.onblur=function jpBlur() { if (this.value == '') this.value = defaultMsg; }
</script>
```

And later....

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" Columns="30" Rows="6" runat="Server" TextMode="MultiLine" />
```

Does anyone see a reason why this should not be working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this worked and other techniques did not, but this got my HTML to work:

```
    <textarea name="txtMsg" rows="6" cols="30"
      onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" 
      onblur="if(this.value==='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">[Write your message here or call my voice number at (555) 222-1234.]</textarea>
```

The text can be very long, and the control does not seem to care. Also, the text is only written in a single location.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you're creating a html element and you are attaching an event to it.
In addition, ASP.NET controls does not use the server side id.
Here's what you should do :

```
var controlMsg = document.getElementById('<%= txtMessage.ClientID %>');
controlMsg.onfocus = // Some Code ...
controlMsg.onblur = // Some Code ...
```

Comment: That's still not working. I've tried several variations of this, and my page isn't happy with anything I do. I just noticed I changed my text, but the old text is still showing. Perhaps my localhost is caching the data and not showing my latest changes.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an anonymous function, like this:

```
controlMsg.onfocus=function() { if ( ...
```

[Functions and function scope - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/).

Also, you did call something like `document.body.appendChild(controlMsg);`, didn't you?

**EDIT:**

You are using `doc.createElement`. Make sure that `doc` definitely points to `document`.

Also, look at the page in Firefox and see if there are any errors or warnings in the Error Console.

Comment: You may be onto something. I've got some sort of [Client Side validation script being dumped to the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751725). Would you happen to understand if functions and scope could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version your are using.Please Try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
 {
   txtMessage. Attributes["onfocus"]="JavascriptMethod";  
 }
```